# Singleton as performance upgrade in access to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I'm writting a .NET application that implements different design patterns.
I have an idea to write singleton + flyweight pattern example.
Let's imagine I have remote database with Pizzas & ingredients. My idea is to:
on app start I would download all Pizzas and Ingredients and keep them in flyweight pattern class. Thanks to this I hope to achieve some memory save.

Moreover:I'd like to implement Singleton pattern, so the download objects are accessible without asking database. Won't this save me time, while accessing database?

Now I would only have to insert orders into database without asking for data.

Please tell me if this explanation for singleton & flyweight is reasonable.

Comment: I am aware that singleton is not recommended pattern but the point is to show its iplementation

Comment: Why you need singleton for that? Why you can't make a static class that will references to `HttpRuntime.Cache` and store downloaded objects there and have some method for returning them from cache?

Comment: Good point, tho my exercise is to implement few design patterns and, tbh, I cannot find reasonable use of singleton

Comment: This would be the caching pattern, and you'd first have to make sure all concurrencies are handled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyweight is when you have many different kinds of a single thing.

Singleton is when you have a single thing.

For example, you might use the Flyweight Pattern to describe countries. One object for Canada, one for Russia, etc. They are both countries, and share similar properties but are not necessary identical.

In contrast, you might use a singleton to represent the Earth, there can only be one Object of the Earth Class.

As for loading the whole database on start, that seems unnecessary and bad practice, a database is for holding information which you can retrieve. If you will be using the same call many times you should cache results, and if you have a huge database which requires lots of text base search you should use a lucene based search server, etc. etc.

However for simple unique SQL or LINQ calls (with EF) to a database you should call when you need to utilize the results of said call.